# Dimension changing of fbx model in unity 3D

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d, fbx

Is it possible to change width of any fbx model in 3D without changing its realistic look so that after changing its dimension, the model should not be stretched?

If 2 objects are placed beside each other then need to increase the size of one object and change position of other object with respect to first object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly are you talking about? if your model for example is a human, it will always be streched if you scale only one coordinate in unity. What exactly are you trying to archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this breaks down to two problems, if you want to scale an object in just one dimension it will always stretch, for example your your table: [image: comparison table streched]
While the board looks fine the legs will get stretched and look unrealistic.
Now the question is what can you do?
It depends on your model.

First of all has your model only one mesh? or has every component a single mesh?
Preferably you want your components to have a independent mesh object. For your table it would be something like this:

[image: mesh single components]

This way you can only scale your board and then transform the position of your legs accordingly so that they fit to the new board size.
If you have only one mesh there is not a lot you can do in Unity. For that you would need to go into Blender or any other 3D modeling tool and split the components manually.

Now if you only stretched the board and your model has a texture you will notice that it will look stretched.

What can you do about that?
Go to your texture and first of all check the wrap mode
[image: Wrapmode repeat]

in this case we want it on repeat, after that we need to change the material setting

[image: tiling]

since we stretched the geometry we need to change the tiling, befor it was on y = 1 but we scaled the y dimensions so now we need to adapt this number aswell and make the texture repeat. For a table this is doable, if we for example work with more complex textures that have specific parts this will not work and you have to change the texture manually.

[image: problem with tiling]

now the texture looks better but you probably will have abrupt color changes, this is because the texture is repeated, i "circled" it on the picture. For this problem you have to change the texture in a picture editing program and make it seamless.

I hope this helped a bit, i know this is only the basics and to get a perfect texture and image you have to put in a bit more work, but for that i would highly recommend to read a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for the help and guiding each step, I will follow and try this

Comment: If texture and color is not the matter, then for example in shower cubical  how to increase the width of glass without increasing the width of its support

Comment: i dont quite understand what you mean

Comment: Shared screenshot in this link, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203397/change-dimensions-of-cubical-shower-3d-model-in-unity-3d