# Change dimensions of Cubical Shower 3d model in unity 3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d, fbx

I am working on a project which is having cubical shower as a 3d model and it is having two different sides as mentioned side 1 and side 2.
Further side 1 is divided into two screens and it is having glass, frames and support and same for screen 2 of side 1.

I want to increase the width of glass without changing the width of support and frames size and even the model should look like real.

Is it possible to change width of any fbx model in 3D without changing its realistic look so that after changing its dimension, the model should not be stretched?

**Updated**
I tried your given solution and following are some of observations:

1. The model is placed in right angled, so how to dynamically identified which axis of particular side should be changed ?
2. If glass object of side 1 is changed then support object is not changing its position so how to keep them connected ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes but you will have to completely unpack the model or do it on runtime

Comment: Is it possible to change only glass width without changing the size of border in runtime ? and how to do it ?

Comment: I don't see any border .. but yes if you get a reference to the `glass` object you can change its `transform.localScale`

Comment: The support game object is actually border.

Comment: Well then there is no problem .. if you only change the scale of the `glass` gameObject, the others won't be changed .. it will only affect everything nested below the `glass` ..

Comment: I want to increase side1_screen1 width, but support should not increase. Any other method or approach  will be appreciated.

Comment: Scale the children you don't want to be affected in the opposite direction e.g. you want to change the scale of `side1_screen1.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (2, 1, 1);` then you'll have to scale the children e.g. `support.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0.5f, 1, 1);` (assuming there are no rotations of course)

Comment: I tried your solution and updated the question above regarding my observation.